# Set scrollbar width to zero on some pages but leave it normal on others

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a react based website and I want to check my location path and optionally have the scrollbar enabled and disabled, since it's a global property on the page and any css imported will be applied globally it doesn't seem to work well.
Essentially on all but one component, I want the scrollbar to be enabled. on that component, users can only scroll via buttons(to only certain areas in the page), I am using react scroll for the same. To disable scrolling via other means I am using the disable-scroll package.
Disable scroll works fine but since I want programmatic scrolling to be enabled I can not set disable scroll to on/true(globally)

These are the settings I've added to disabling user input.

```
disableScroll.on(
        {},
        {
            authorizedInInputs: [32, 37, 38, 39, 40],
            disableKeys: true,
            disableScroll: false,
            disableWheel: true,
            keyboardKeys: [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
        }
    );
```

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

TL;DR: Set scrollbar width to zero on one location and keep default values everywhere else

Comment: Add a wrapper class where you wanted to change the scroll width size, just go adjust the scroll width of it, rest you can keep rest of the styling as it is.

Comment: That only works for firefox if I'm not wrong, webkit scrollbar needs to be attached on the body right?
To clarify I want the main scrollbar width to be disabled on a component that is responsible to render the entire page